# Jumping to content location of a different page with ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, hyperlink, anchor, jump-list

Does anyone know how to jump to the content location from a href link on another page in **ASP**?

I understand the anchor concept shown below, but this only works with html not **ASP**.

```
<a href="yoursite.html#jumpHere">link</a>
```

Comment: <a href="yoursite.html#jumpHere">link</a> - ASP is a server side technology; all the client sees is html.  Do you have a specific example of what you are trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

Anchor tags work with other file formats than `.html`.

Any file which is rendered as `html` content, can use anchor tags.

Therefore, your link could be:

```
<a href="yoursite.aspx#jumpHere">link</a>
```

Then as long as there is an element on the rendered `yoursite.aspx` content with ID `jumpHere`, the browser will "jump" to that element.